# How do I save the states of an RNN to file from a Graph in TF?

Tags: c++, tensorflow

The following code is from the tensorflow serving API:

```
// Implementation of Predict using the SavedModel SignatureDef format.
Status SavedModelPredict(const RunOptions& run_options, ServerCore* core,
                         const PredictRequest& request,
                         PredictResponse* response) {
  // Validate signatures.
  ServableHandle<SavedModelBundle> bundle;
  TF_RETURN_IF_ERROR(core->GetServableHandle(request.model_spec(), &bundle));

  const string signature_name = request.model_spec().signature_name().empty()
                                    ? kDefaultServingSignatureDefKey
                                    : request.model_spec().signature_name();
  auto iter = bundle->meta_graph_def.signature_def().find(signature_name);
  if (iter == bundle->meta_graph_def.signature_def().end()) {
    return errors::FailedPrecondition(strings::StrCat(
        "Serving signature key \"", signature_name, "\" not found."));
  }
  SignatureDef signature = iter->second;

  MakeModelSpec(request.model_spec().name(), signature_name,
                bundle.id().version, response->mutable_model_spec());

  std::vector<std::pair<string, Tensor>> input_tensors;
  std::vector<string> output_tensor_names;
  std::vector<string> output_tensor_aliases;
  TF_RETURN_IF_ERROR(PreProcessPrediction(signature, request, &input_tensors,
                                          &output_tensor_names,
                                          &output_tensor_aliases));
  std::vector<Tensor> outputs;
  RunMetadata run_metadata;
  TF_RETURN_IF_ERROR(bundle->session->Run(run_options, input_tensors,
                                          output_tensor_names, {}, &outputs,
                                          &run_metadata));

  return PostProcessPredictionResult(signature, output_tensor_aliases, outputs,
                                     response);
}
```

This code runs a prediction with a stored model. In my case, this stored model is an RNN.

After the following line where the prediction is actually run:

```
TF_RETURN_IF_ERROR(bundle->session->Run(run_options, input_tensors,
                                      output_tensor_names, {}, &outputs,
                                      &run_metadata));
```

I want to save the states of the RNN to a file/memory so that I can access them at a later date after each prediction. I assume these states can be accessed via the variable:

```
bundle->meta_graph_def
```

but am unclear on exactly how to access specifically the state values of the RNN and then to save them to a file.

Answer (score 0):

You have to get the values via the session, not after the fact. In your line

```
bundle->session->Run(run_options, input_tensors,
                                  output_tensor_names, {}, &outputs,
                                  &run_metadata)
```

You should not only request the result of the prediction, but also the state tensor. Note that the value of the state is not stored after the particular call to `session->Run`, only variables are stored, the state of the RNN is a computed value and dropped after the results you requested are returned.

I don't use the c++ interface, so forgive me for giving a code example in python, hopefully it's still of use (I bet this isn't the first time you've had to put up with reading a python example), in python this would look like:

```
prediction, state = sess.run([prediction_tensor, state_tensor], feed_dict=...)
```